# Server-Sent Event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I got this code from W3Schools.com, its an example of server-sent event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
  {
  var source=new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+="<br>" + event.data;
    };
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how to edit the code so that new entry comes above the old entry?
I am unable to figure out how to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+="<br>" + event.data;
```

takes the document and APPENDS the new data to it.

Im surprised you havent tried

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =event.data + "<br>" + document.getElementById("result").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Can I implement this while creating a shoutbox?